# seperating numberic strings from words in php

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a php script that runs a cmd command on my windows machine, i redirect  my standard Output from the command shell back to my php script and I get the following  result:

> Interface Statistics Received Sent Bytes 30750280 8480324
>
> Unicast packets 44928 43160
>
> Non-unicast packets 0 0
>
> Discards 0 0
>
> Errors 0 0
>
> Unknown protocols 0

what i want to do is use RegEx to format the result such that i can out the data in a tabular form like:

```
    interface statistics
received| 3535353535
sent    | 4664646646
errors  | 0
```

in that order.

so far, i just tried formating only the line that contains the " bytes" using the code below without much luck;

```
if (preg_match('/Bytes/',$lines)) {
 $lines = trim($lines);
 $pieces = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $lines);
echo $lines;
echo "Sent: ".(int)$pieces[1]."Reeived: ".$pieces[2];

    preg_match_all('/(\d)|(\w)/', $lines, $matches);

    $numbers = implode($matches[1]);
    $letters = implode($matches[2]);

//var_dump($numbers, $letters);
//echo $numbers;
//echo  $letters."letters";

}
```

Comment: One liner: https://regex101.com/r/PqfvPq/3

Answer (score 0):

Code: ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2189f9bdc484dc8dde9173784d537246a154d2f)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ugvUtv/1))

```
$shell_output='Interface Statistics Received Sent Bytes 30750280 8480324

Unicast packets 44928 43160

Non-unicast packets 0 0

Discards 0 0

Errors 0 0

Unknown protocols 0';

$pattern='/Interface Statistics Received Sent Bytes (\d+) (\d+).*Errors (\d+).*/s';
$replace="interface statistics\nreceived| $1\nsent\t| $2\nerrors\t| $3";
echo preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$shell_output);
```

Output:

```
interface statistics
received| 30750280
sent    | 8480324
errors  | 0
```

The pattern uses a literal match on `Interface Statistics Received Sent Bytes` to reduce the step count.  The `s` modifier/flag at the end of the pattern will allow the `.` (dot = any character) to match newline characters.  The pattern is designed to replace the entire text with the new replacement text.